# How to prevent app from getting backed up to iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm having some trouble getting an app accepted into the App Store. The problem is that the database is getting backed up to the iCloud, according to Apple, although I attempted to prevent that by setting the `skipBackupFlag` for the database file to YES [per Apples documantation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

I may have done something wrong, so I'd like to check that before resubmitting the app. Note that I'm storing the DB in the NSLibrary directory with my bundle's identifier appended as a subdirectory, so the actual directory is this:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/DA9AF74B-3735-4325-BE87-F4D3003AD205/Library/com.mycompany.myapp/my.db:
```

As a check, on my iPod I went to "settings", "iCloud storage and backup", "Manage Storage", "show all apps", but my app is showing up as only 1.3 kb. According to Apple, it's backing more than 7mb to iCloud, so for them the backup is including the database file.

One additional question (if I'm unable to figure out how to test the skipBackupFlag)  - is it sufficient to just set the database file's skipBackupFlag to YES, or should the directory's skipBackupFlag also be set?

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out how to test the skipBackupFlag, but I'm pretty sure I was setting it incorrectly. Once I patched that, the app was accepted. The data's not getting backed up, and it's stored in NSDirectory.

Comment: I really don't understand how this "key" works. Once I've set the "NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey" key with "-(BOOL)setSourceValue:forKey:" method, I get no error and the BOOL is YES, should I be ok?

Comment: By the way, I just found a way to test if the flag is set (in the iPhone Simulator)! You should open the terminal and cd to the folder containing the file and execute the following command: ls -al -@